# Wrong and ugly output of an arrow

Tags: amsmath, arrows

I have a weird output regarding `xrightarrow{}`. Why is that happening? How can I fix it?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.3in, bottom=1.2in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in]{geometry}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\everymath{\displaystyle}

\allowdisplaybreaks

\setlength{\mathindent}{0cm}

\newcommand{\CCMG}[1]
{\begin{gather*}#1\end{gather*}}

\newcommand{\CCMAD}[1]
{\begin{aligned}#1\end{aligned}}

\newcommand{\CCMA}[1]
{\begin{align*}#1\end{align*}}


\begin{document}
\raggedcolumns

\CCMG
{
\CCMAD
{
&g'(\xi_{n})=\frac{g(x_{n})-g(\rho)}{x_{n}-\rho}\Rightarrow\\
&\Rightarrow g(x_{n})=g(\rho)+g'(\xi_{n})\epsilon_{n}\xrightarrow{g(\rho)=\rho,g(x_{n})=x_{n+1}}
}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Am pretty sure that is just a PDF display issue. Try zooming in and out.

Comment: @PeterGrill that was what I thought too but it didn't work.

Comment: Seems that the `\usepackage{unicode-math}` is causing this problem with XeLaTeX.

Comment: Logically therefore a package bug: 'off topic'

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a package bug.